# Stop TinyMCE adding <br /> tags instead of just putting something on a new line

Tags: tinymce

So on the website I am designing I have created a cms and one of the things I want to allow people to do is edit the code examples on page (it's an educational website that allows teachers to sign up), I am using TinyMCE as the editor. However, when I'm testing it I notice that if I go to change the example to something like:

```
alert("Hello nstudent "); 
document.write("Hello Student");
```

it will show up on the page with them side by side with a `<br/>` tag between them. Please see this screenshot showing what I mean
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVHPj.png).

Is there a way to stop TinyMCE from adding the `<br/>` tag and just put them on a new line like I'm wanting?

This is how I have set it up:

```
      tinymce.init({

       selector: "textarea",
          force_br_newlines : false,
          force_p_newlines : false,
          forced_root_block : '',
          invalid_elements:"div",


          plugins: [

              "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",

              "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",

              "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste"

          ],

          toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image"

      });
```

I have spent ages trying to find a solution but nothing seems to be working so any guidance would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You likely need to clarify your expectations of the code you want to render to your web site.  TinyMCE is an HTML editor so when you ask it to give you content it will give you HTML - it is odd you are using an HTML editor but stating you don't want HTML.

Based on how you have TinyMCE configured (specifically `forced_root_block : ''`) pressing the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key inserts the `<br>` tag.  If you did not have that setting each press of the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key inserts a new block / paragraph (`<p></p>` by default).

As you are using an HTML editor what are you wanting the editor to do when you press the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key?  Moving to a "new line" is either a new block or a line break.  What are you wanting TinyMCE to do if not one of these HTML constructs?

Comment: I guess what I was wondering is if it was possible adjust it to have javascript as well but what I've done now is just change it to a normal text area so the code can be adjusted from there without any issues